# Fails to build OpenCV 3 with Python2 support

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I tried to build opencv 3 with python support (with cuda, too) for Ubuntu 14.04 using CMake-gui.

The compilation seems to work fine until from a Python console:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

I tried both with python3 enabled or disabled without change. The [cmakeCache.txt is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-YDFMbEy1grRW9Kb09oX0FMdWM/view?usp=sharing) here.

Any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: building from opencv 3 beta doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem since yesterday, and I solved it as follows:

1. Download OpenCV 3(beta, rc1) and install all the necessary dependencies, including Python dev package.
2. Open Cmake GUI.
3. Activate the **Grouped** checkbox.
4. Select the OpenCV source and build directories (or just delete the cache if you previously configured).
5. Press **Configure**. Select your preferred generator.
6. Check/uncheck the options you need to (OpenGL support, TBB, etc.)

   - If you want, you can press **Configure** after every option modification to see if it fails or not. Just ignore the Python2 options for now.
7. Once you have configured all other options, select the PYTHON2 group and delete it with **Remove entry**.
8. Press **Configure**. The PYTHON2 group will reappear, in red. Do not change anything more, just press **Generate**.

Now you can make/compile the usual way. The cv2.so file will be created in build/lib/ directory. With make install it will be installed for Python 2.

If it still does not work maybe the problem is somewhere else. After step 8, the cmake output must include the lines (actual paths might be different in your case):

```
Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

In no case there can be a line saying NO, like:

```
Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
    Libraries:                   NO
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If it compiles fine, then the probem isn't with cmake or the way your build options are set. The problem looks like it isn't with python2 or 3 either, but the way you have OpenCV installed. After you compile OpenCV you have to move your opencv python modules to /usr/local/lib or python won't be able to see them.